# Social Network gem / plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Has anyone built a social networking app using any of the gems/plugins/engines currently available? A post like this is 4 years old, so I am asking the question again. Any recommendations?

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/social_networking

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and not found ready-made solution for my goals. After a brief study of the problem, the necessary features were gathered from the gems. A short list of them:

```
gem "devise", ">= 2.1.0.rc"
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem "simple_form"
gem "nested_form"
gem "chosen-rails"
gem "cancan"
gem "activeadmin"
gem "opinio"
gem "geocoder"
gem "gmaps4rails"
gem "sunspot_rails"
gem "sunspot_solr"
gem "thumbs_up"
```

This list was enough for me to make a small social network without much effort.
Depending on your goals may be easier to take a complete solution or a set of gems.